# Vue3 transition-group, enter active animation is not working while leave is working

Tags: vue.js, data-visualization, transition

I tried to animate addition and deletion of element in v-for loop.
I searched some similar quesitons here and mainly the answers were about
class name change in vue3 from vue2.

I'm sure my case is not related to class name.
My code is as below.

**Component name: VueOnly**

```
    <transition-group tag='div' class='VueOnly' name='fade'>
      <div class='graphs' v-for="boro in lotteriesByBorough" :key="boro['value']">

        <div>{{boro[0]}}</div>
        <div class="bargraph" :style="{width: xScale(boro[1]) + 'px'}"></div>

      </div>
     </transition-group>
     <div style='display:none'>{{console}}</div>

</template>
```

*css

```
.fade-enter-active{
  animation:fade-in 1s 
}

.fade-leave-active{
  animation:fade-in 1s reverse
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from{
    opacity:0  ;
    width:0 ;
    background-color:blue ;
  }
  to{
    opacity:1;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

I strongly believe I am following the syntax of 
why is this not working?

It works only when 'leave' event is triggered.
Temporary class is added when 'leave' events are running while no class is added when 'enter' events are running.

So I think there is a problem in enter process in general.

Does it have anything to do with addition logic?

My addition logic is as below.
**App.vue**

```
<div class="filters">
        <el-checkbox-group v-model="filters">
          <el-checkbox label="1"></el-checkbox>
          <el-checkbox label="2"></el-checkbox>
          <el-checkbox label="3"></el-checkbox>
          <el-checkbox label="4"></el-checkbox>
        </el-checkbox-group>
      </div>

      <div class="section" :style="{width:`${width}px`,height:`${height}px`}">
        <vue-only 
        :lotteries="filteredLotteries"
        :lottery-stats="lotteryStats"
        :width="width"
        >
        </vue-only>
      </div>
The entire code can be seen in the following link.
```

https://github.com/jotnajoa/studioquestion/tree/main/d3vue

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`appear` property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#transitions-on-initial-render) on `<transition-group>`:

```html
<transition-group tag="div" class="VueOnly" name="fade" appear>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/animating-transition-group-on-initial-render-sn7ew?file=/src/App.vue:117-123)

Comment: @AdamReis No, unfortunately not. I recommend posting a new question with details on how to reproduce the issue so that someone familiar with the topic can answer. I'll chime in if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. It seems that the class `animation_name-enter-active` is not applied to new items (regardless of using `appear` or not). But the class `animation_name-enter-to` will be applied normally, so I moved my animation css to this class and it worked. Probably more a workaround than a real solution.